# My websites show a weird character after loading

Tags: url, redirect, ascii, character

I have two websites

```
http://www.buywwetickets.com/
http://www.ufcticketbooth.com/
```

The problem is that sometimes before the websites load it shows me a blank screen with some weird characters at the top left side, and after a second they load normaly, this is just happening on this host, on my local machine and dev host they look fine and this problem never happens.

I'm trying to figure out why this happens but I have no clue, I guess it must be somehow related to the hosting server? Also the characters dissapears too quickly for me to copy them and paste it here, but they're some weird ASCII symbols.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try correcting this by changing your content type using your server-side script, in php it would be:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

There is also a html equivalent, that might not by itself be enough but you should add it:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

If that doesnt work and the character you are talking about is ï»¿ 
then it is BOM for UTF-8, so try saving your source files with "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding if your text editor doesn't do that.